# How to ignore field with org.json.JSONObject(Object)

Tags: java, json

I am using the [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library. I am creating a `JSONObject` like so:

```
Geometry geometry = new Geometry(); 
JSONObject featureObject = new JSONObject(geometry);
```

How can I tell JSONObject to ignore one or more fields of the `Geometry` object? I have tried `@Transient` but that did not work.

Comment: Can't you use `JSONObject.remove()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I ended up figuring this out is to change the name of the `getter` method.

I changed it from `getFieldName()` to `retrieveFieldName()` and this caused the `JSONObject` to ignore it.

As @kolejnik said, though, it would probably be best to switch to a better json library.

Answer (score 7):

At the meantime there is also an anotation for this in the org.json library.

@JSONPropertyIgnore

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [source code](http://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java), method populateMap which is used by JSONObject(Object object) does not support any exceptions in serialization.
There is method public JSONObject(Object object, String names[]) but it works only with public fields.

I would suggest using more powerfull library for parsing to/from JSON like Gson or Jackson. Gson omits transient fields, Jackson has @JsonIgnore annotation for getters.